# How do I view a .rb (Ruby) file?

Tags: ruby

So we just learned Ruby in class today, and we are just starting to write our own scripts.  So I just wrote a very simple "Hello World" app in Ruby.  I saved the file as lab7.rb  .  So now my question is how do I view the output of the file?  Do I open it in a browser?  Thanks

Comment: You probably have to run the file using the ruby interpreter. I think it would be something like `ruby lab7.rb`. The output would only show in a browser window if the script is going to be handled by a server process. Did you set up a server to serve Ruby pages?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: That's good material for an answer. :-)

Comment: @Platinum Azure: Thanks! It's been a long time since I've worked with Ruby (and I never did that much in the first place) so I wasn't 100% sure...

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: Put it down as an answer and I'll vote you up. :-)

Comment: @Platinum Azure: Nah, @OscarRyz is already gonna get this one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to install the ruby interpreter in your machine.

If you're running in Linux or MacOS you probably have it already, try typing:

```
ruby lab7.rb
```

In windows download it here:

http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/